# Visual Studio 2017 strange auto formatting for braces on code blocks

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, editor, visual-studio-2017

OK, I've flipped every setting I was able to find myself, it's stack overflow time. I know Visual Studio formatting questions are a common breed, but this particular one is quite strange to me. It happens when I'm writing a block within a block.

I start with this:

```
void myFunction()
{
    int something = 0;
    if (something == 0)
    {
        ...
}
```

The "..." is where I'm typing. Often I'll complete the block. I don't have auto-complete braces on because I don't do that in every case. So, I hit Enter and the magic happens

```
void myFunction()
{
    int something = 0;
    if (something == 0)
    {

         ...
->  }
```

it indents the brace *below* the line that I'm typing. And it doesn't correct itself. So when I do the last brace I get this:

```
void myFunction()
{
    int something = 0;
    if (something == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
    }
```

This is driving me bonkers. There's about 100 different formatting settings, and I've toggled everything I can find. There also don't seem to be comprehensive docs on this that I can find. Even when I flip the formatting settings I like off, it still manages to do this one thing.

So, how do I disable this feature?

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. My TOP curly is indented, the others are fine. I switched to "block" tabs, both on All languages, and specifically on C#. It is not ideal, but, it is better than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you're using, they each surface formatting settings separately.  There should be settings for this in Tools -> Options under Text Editor -> [Language].

For example, for C# it would be under C# -> Code Style -> Formatting, and you're probably looking for the 'Automatically format on return' checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed this is the first thing I tried, but that option does not seem to govern this behavior unfortunately.